# How to setState more than one object and pass to other component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new at react-native. I try a lot of ways to get arrays of JSON data from openweathermap's API but didn't work. I want some suggestions and guidelines.
I just fetch JSON data and want to set state more than one object from JSON data.

Example of JSON data. I want to get temp, humidity, description and icon from 2 arrays in list[].

```
"list":[  
  {  
     "dt":1541440800,
     "main":{  
        "temp":25.85,
        "temp_min":25.85,
        "temp_max":27.35,
        "pressure":1022.17,
        "sea_level":1023.04,
        "grnd_level":1022.17,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":-1.5
     },
     "weather":[  
        {  
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10n"
        }
     ],
     "dt_txt":"2018-11-05 18:00:00"
  },
  {  
     "dt":1541451600,
     "main":{  
        "temp":26.38,
        "temp_min":26.38,
        "temp_max":27.5,
        "pressure":1021.34,
        "sea_level":1022.24,
        "grnd_level":1021.34,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":-1.12
     },
     "weather":[  
        {  
           "id":802,
           "main":"Clouds",
           "description":"scattered clouds",
           "icon":"03n"
        }
     ],
     "dt_txt":"2018-11-05 21:00:00"
  }
```

Here is my JSON fetching component.  I want to show different data from arrays by passing state to front-end component.

```
export default class Forecast extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hourlyForecast: {}
    };
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${
        this.props.currentCity
      }&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          hourlyForecast: {
            temp: json.list[0].main.temp,
            humidity: json.list[0].main.humidity,
            icon: json.list[0].weather[0].icon,
            description: json.list[0].weather[0].description,
            date_time: json.list[0].dt_txt
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.warn(error);
      });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => this.fetchData();

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
        <ForecastCards {...this.state.hourlyForecast} />
        <ForecastCards {...this.state.hourlyForecast} />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my front-end component.

```
export default class ForecastCards extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <Card>
            <CardItem>
              <Body>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "row"}}>
                  <View>
                    <Text>{this.props.date_time}</Text>
                    <Text>Temperature: {this.props.temp} °C</Text>
                    <Text>Humidity: {this.props.humidity} %</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{marginLeft: 100}}>
                     <Image
                      style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }}
                      source={{
                        uri: `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${
                          this.props.icon
                        }.png`
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text>{this.props.description}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If so pls mention them

Comment: I don't get any

Comment: Use redux and axios. This is not a good design

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```
fetchData = () => {
  fetch(
    `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${this.props.currentCity}&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`
  )
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({
      hourlyForecast: {
        temp: json.list[0].main.temp,
        humidity: json.list[0].main.humidity,
        icon: json.list[0].weather[0].icon,
        description: json.list[0].weather[0].description,
        date_time: json.list[0].dt_txt
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.warn(error);
  });
};

componentDidMount = () => this.fetchData();

render() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <ForecastCards hourlyForecast={this.state.hourlyForecast} />
        <ForecastCards hourlyForecast={this.state.hourlyForecast} />
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

And here is my front-end component.

```
export default class ForecastCards extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardItem>
          <Body>
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "row"}}>
              <View>
                <Text>{this.props.hourlyForecast.date_time}</Text>
                <Text>Temperature: {this.props.hourlyForecast.temp} °C</Text>
                <Text>Humidity: {this.props.hourlyForecast.humidity} %</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{marginLeft: 100}}>
                 <Image
                  style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }}
                  source={{
                    uri: `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${
                      this.props.hourlyForecast.icon
                    }.png`
                  }}
                />
                <Text>{this.props.hourlyForecast.description}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Body>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

ForecastCards.propTypes = {
  hourlyForecast: PropTypes.object
}
```

Setting the state is fine. For passing the props `<ForecastCards hourlyForecast={this.state.hourlyForecast} />`

Provide the PropType in `ForecastCards` component using `ForecastCards.propTypes = {
  hourlyForecast: PropTypes.object
}`

For access date_time or any other key, please use `this.props.hourlyForecast.date_time` or `this.props.hourlyForecast.{key}`

Hope this will help you.